# How to get an unbiased estimator

Tags: self-study, mean, bias, unbiased-estimator, estimators

Defining the sample mean as $\bar{x} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_n$, and having $N$ realizations of a random variable $x$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$
Defining  $\bar{x}^2=\hat{\mu^2}$, I get that $Bias(\bar{x}^2) = E[\bar{x}^2] - \mu^2=E[\bar{x}]^2+Var(\bar{x}) - \mu^2 = \mu^2+ \frac{\sigma^2}{N} - \mu^2 = \frac{\sigma^2}{N}$ is a biased estimator.
Would it be possible to obtain an unbiased estimator of $\mu^2$?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please define $Bias(\bar{x}^2)$ and consider adding the self-study tag.

Comment: Why are you omitting the last observation in your definition of the sample mean? If you're trying to use [Bessel's correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction), that requires changing the divisor, not removing an observation, and it can only do you any good when estimating a variance, not a mean.

Comment: An alternative view to *unbiasedness* is presented in this Gelman blog post ... http://andrewgelman.com/2015/06/10/best-linear-unbiased-prediction-is-exactly-like-the-holy-roman-empire/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $X_1, \dots, X_N \sim (\mu, \sigma^2)$. Then observe that 
$$\mu^2 = \mu_2 + \sigma^2$$
where I am using $\mu_2$ to represent the second moment $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$.

Then, [a well-known unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator#Sample_variance) is 
$$S^2 = \dfrac{1}{N-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N}(X_i-\bar{X})^2$$
where $\bar{X} = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i}{N}$.

Furthermore, in general, if we have a function $g$ such that $\mathbb{E}[g(X_i)] = k$ for each $i$ (i.e., the expected value is the same for each variable in the random sample), we can use
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\dfrac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}g(X_i)\right] = \dfrac{1}{N}(Nk)=k\text{,}$$
which means, that, therefore, $\dfrac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}g(X_i)$ is an unbiased estimator of $k$. Use this to find an unbiased estimator of $\mu_2$.